# Code Snippet Works in Certain Cases but not as Expected, Why?

Tags: c++, parsing, object, loops, cin

I have this code snippet that is supposed to test whether the user enters an integer or not. This works if the user enters letters, but not decimals and I'm left wondering why that is. Here's my code snippet:

```
Student student;
int id;

while(!(cin >> id))
{
    cout << "\nERROR: Please enter a Positive Whole Number" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore ();
    cout << "Enter Student ID: ";
}
```

Entering `A` will make it iterate through the while loop, but if I enter `12.5` it drops out of the while loop and keeps going. Isn't it testing whether it will parse to integer or not? Why is it accepting `12.5` but not characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin>>id` will succeed as long as it finds *something* it can convert to an `int` ("12", in this case). When it reaches something it can't convert, it stops, but if it's read an `int` already, that counts as success.

To check that *everything* it read was digits, you might want to do something like using `std::getline` to read a line of input into a string, then use `std::isdigit` to test whether those are all digits. Testing a conversion to `int` (by itself) will only tell you that it found something that could be read as an integer, but won't tell you if that was followed by other things that couldn't be converted to an `int`.

Comment: See I tried `isdigit()` but I also kept getting true instances with 12.5 so I started searching for a new solution. Will try again though Thanks!

Comment: You could also try `boost::lexical_cast`, which doesn't accept 123abc and the like.